# Cannot set data in variable after loading with useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am doing an online fullstack course for University of Helsinki and it is wanting me to use a weather and climate API to show information about the country and its current weather.

So I have three components: App, Lister, and Country. Inside App I make a useEffect call with axios to get the data for a list of countries. From there I want it so that when you click on the button or search it should show information about the country, including weather. To do that, when information about the specific country is shown, I have another useEffect call to an API for the weather. However, while the first API call seems to store the data on the list of countries, the second call does not.

I have tried changing the dependency of the second useEffect call to [name], but that also does not bring results, and when I just log the information with that type of dependency, I just see an infinite amount of calls in the console. Have tried with other API's just to see if I was miscalling it somehow but even those resulted in the same situation.

Inside the App component I do a call to get info about all the countries and it works fine.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Lister from './Lister';

const App = () => {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all').then(r => setPlaces(r.data));
  }, []);
.....
```

Everything works fine in here. I'm able to see and search and all that. I then have it call Lister which just maps the data from the country-search API into using the Country component.

```
.....
  const listPlaces = () => {
    if (results.length === 1) {
      return (
        <div>
          {results.map(r => (
            <Country
              key={r.population / r.name.length + 5}
              name={r.name}
              capital={r.capital}
              population={r.population}
              languages={r.languages}
              image={r.flag}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

This is where the main crux of the issue is, in Country. When I call useeffect again, this time for the weather api, it doesn't seem to set it to the weather variable

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Country = ({ name, capital, population, languages, image }) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  // have tried useState(), useState([]), useState({})
  const accessKey = '';

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/...`)
      .then(r => {
        setWeather(r.data);
        console.log(r.data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='Country'>
        <h1>Name: {name}</h1>
        <p>Capital: {capital}</p>
        <p>Population: {population}</p>

        <h2>Languages</h2>
        <ul>
          {languages.map(l => (
            <li key={l.name.length}>{l.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <img src={image} alt="Country's flag" height='100' width='100' />
      </div>

      <div className='Weather'>
        <h1>Weather {weather.current.temperature} </h1>
        <h2>Temperature </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Country;
```

Weather will be of type undefined even though the log shows that the data was loaded, so should it not be set by the setWeather call?

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox for this?

Comment: A few observations:
1-) what does this if check do in listPlaces? I think it is unnecessary if you want to display all countries.
if (results.length === 1)
2-) Countries have natural key values like alpha2Code, so it is better to change this line  key={r.population / r.name.length + 5}   to
key={r.alpha2Code} 
same problem when setting key to languages
3-) Weather api seems to return an object as response, but you set the initial state to empty array with [].
 const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);  =>  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});